# Need help identifying this small tree

Tags: trees

It's a small tree in a very shaded area approx 7 feet tall. Northern Indiana
[image][image] BJ

Answer (score 1):

The tree is a Sassafras tree (Sassafras albidum). It is native to eastern North America. Here are a couple of links.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sassafras_albidum

http://www.bio.brandeis.edu/fieldbio/emmae24/Lauraceae/sassafras.html